# C# - Process | Манипуляции

Tags: c#

C#
Пример: BEService.exe - Приостановлено. Как добиться такого эффекта? Чтобы приложение .exe было приостановлено, в то время как те же службы выполняются.
Делал много манипуляций в C# с process, но такого эффекта "Приостановлено" так и не получил.[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById("process pid");
process.Suspend();

public static class ProcessExtension
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

    public static void Suspend(this Process process)
    {
        foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
        {
            var pOpenThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)thread.Id);
            if (pOpenThread == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                break;
            }
            SuspendThread(pOpenThread);
        }
    }
    public static void Resume(this Process process)
    {
        foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
        {
            var pOpenThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)thread.Id);
            if (pOpenThread == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                break;
            }
            ResumeThread(pOpenThread);
        }
    }
}
```